# Path dependent vector transformation in R

Tags: r

I have a vector in a dataframe in R which is a time series that oscillates between 0 and 100. 
I am wanting to create a new column/vector in R that has that will be series on 1s and 0s. It will be 1 when the time series drops below 10 and will continue to be 1 until it reaches 80. Thereafter it will go back to zero. So there is a path dependency in this problem I am wanting to solve.

Something like;

```
DataFrame %>% mutate(BinaryIndicator = ....)
```

I think the picture below will be the easiest way to show what I am wanting to get to. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Here is a link to an example of what I would like to create

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: And you'll have multiple such instances when series drops below 10?

Comment: yes correct, there will be multiple instances where is drops below 10 and rises above 80 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value of one row depends on the value of the previous row (after its value is updated from *its* previous row, etc), I think a rolling-window operation is appropriate. `zoo` does this well.

```r
dat <- data.frame(x=rep(c(60, 50, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10.2, 9, 2, 3, 9, 40, 72, 81, 90), 2))
dat$binary <- cumsum(zoo::rollapply(dat$x, 2, function(a) {
  if (length(a) < 2) return(0)
  if (a[1] >= 10 && a[2] <  10) return(1)
  if (a[1] <  80 && a[2] >= 80) return(-1)
  return(0)
}, partial = TRUE, align = "right"))
dat
#       x binary
# 1  60.0      0
# 2  50.0      0
# 3  40.0      0
# 4  35.0      0
# 5  30.0      0
# 6  25.0      0
# 7  20.0      0
# 8  15.0      0
# 9  10.2      0
# 10  9.0      1
# 11  2.0      1
# 12  3.0      1
# 13  9.0      1
# 14 40.0      1
# 15 72.0      1
# 16 81.0      0
# 17 90.0      0
# 18 60.0      0
# 19 50.0      0
# 20 40.0      0
# 21 35.0      0
# 22 30.0      0
# 23 25.0      0
# 24 20.0      0
# 25 15.0      0
# 26 10.2      0
# 27  9.0      1
# 28  2.0      1
# 29  3.0      1
# 30  9.0      1
# 31 40.0      1
# 32 72.0      1
# 33 81.0      0
# 34 90.0      0
```

(I wonder if the internal logic can be simplified some.)

Comment: I another question, if the series where to start with a number of NAs;  for example 10 NA's then the time series starts thereafter, how would you write the code then?

Comment: That depends a little, but perhaps the first condition could be `length(a) || anyNA(a)`.